# Errors "This action is unauthorized." using Form Request validations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization, laravel-10

I make some gate like this:

```php
Gate::define('update-post', function  ($user, Post $post) {
    return $user->hasAccess(['update-post']) or $user->id == $post->user_id;
});
```

I checked my database and it has update-post access and the user id is same as in the post. but I got:

> This action is unauthorized.

errors. so am I do some mistake here? thanks.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I had  a similar problem some time ago when starting to use [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#form-request-validation) classes for data validation. I noticed the following:

If you are using [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#form-request-validation) to validate data, then first of all, **check that you set properly the authorization rule that will allow it to pass**. This is handled by the `authorize()` method that must return a `boolean`, **that by default is set to** `false`:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests\Users;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()   
    {
        /** 
         * By default it returns false, change it to 
         * something like this if u are checking authentication
         */
        return Auth::check(); // <-------

        /** 
         * You could also use something more granular, like
         * a policy rule or an admin validation like this:
         * return auth()->user()->isAdmin();
         * 
         * Or just return true if you handle the authorisation
         * anywhere else:
         * return true;
         */ 
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        // your validations...
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! I'd just improve the answer saying to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Answer (score 26):

Make sure you return **true** on "authorize" method

```php
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: For Laravel 9: `public function authorize($ability, $arguments = [])`

Comment: That looks risky... You're authorizing ANYONE to run it. Something like `return $this->user() != null;` is a bit safer, as only logged-in users would be authorized.

Answer (score 11):

For Laravel 8(also applicable to Laravel 9) go to
folder app->http->requests
choose the class file(in my case it was StoreStudentRequest.php) and in function **authorize** set return value to true;

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurred to me when I did not `return true` in `php artisan make:request SellRequest`
 in function`public function authorize()`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SellRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
        public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'city'=>'required',
            'address'=>'required',
            'type'=>'required',
            'land'=>'required',
            'area'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to authorize function return true

```
public function authorize()
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

and then add auth facade or use Auth;

Answer (score 2):

```php
<?php 
namespace App\Modules\UserManagement\Request;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Response;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
     /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {

        $rules = [
            'full_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            're_enter_password' => 'required'
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured your authorize() and you still have the same problem, you may check your route/api.php You may have a error declaring the same path for 2 Controller.

```
Route::resource('users', UserController::class)/*authorized true*/;
Route::resource('users', User2Controller::class)/*unauthorized true*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your controller

```
**use Illuminate\Http\Request;**
```

instead of

```
use App\Http\Requests\StoreGameRequest;
```

and change the parameter in function as

```
public function store(**Request $request**)
    {
        $request->validate([
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was not doing the right check in `Gate::define(...)`

So maybe double check your logic in that function