# 403 : This action is unauthorized

Tags: laravel, vue.js, request, inertiajs

I'm trying to send a user update request using Inertia `manual visitis`, as mentioned in the documentation `https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection`, Laravel automatically includes the proper CSRF token when making requests via Inertia, however my request returns `403 : THIS ACTIONS IS UNAUTHORIZED`:

`Index.vue`

```
const saveUser = () => {
    router.put(`users/${user.value}`);
    submitted.value = true;
    createUserDialog.value = false;
    user.value = {};
};
```

`UserController.php`

```
    public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request)
    {
        $request->user()->fill($request->validated());

        if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
            $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
        }

        $request->user()->save();

    }
```

`web.php`

```
Route::Resource('users', UserController::class)->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128903/errors-this-action-is-unauthorized-using-form-request-validations-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

I see you made a UserUpdateRequest.php file. Make sure to check in your UserUpdateRequest.php file for the authorize() function. This function handles the request first by checking if the request is authorized. The idea is that you put the authorization logic here. By default the function returns false, which means you will never be authorized hence you get 403:

```
  public function authorize(): bool
{
    return false;
}
```

If you just want to see if the user is logged in:

```
 public function authorize(): bool
{
    return Auth::check();
}
```

You could also check for specific permissions here if you have them implemented in your model. Maybe you have specific accounts that can update users, for example:

```
  public function authorize(): bool
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return $user()->hasPermission('canUpdateUser');
}
```

If you just want a quick and easy fix set it to return true:

```
  public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

I would recommend to implement policies instead, if you haven't yet. Then you can move your authorization code from this file to your policy file and reuse it in other Request files.

I hope it helped.